There's a node in the middle of my character when exporting from Blender to Mixamo
I've created a character in ready player me. I imported it to Blender but when I export it to Mixamo an esphere appears in the middle of the character. It is a viewer node in blender I think.What should I do? And where Is the problem? A viewer node appears when I import the character to blender and I dont know how to delete it.

Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add images of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.

Thank you very much Ive added some details.

There is a hidden Icosphere inside your scene. By default the FBX exporter exports hidden objects. Find the hidden object in the Outliner and delete it.
You can also press Alt + H to reveal all object hidden in viewport.
